# Cannot find module when executing a node script from powershell with arguments

Tags: node.js, powershell, scripting

I have a scenario that requires me to execute a node script from within powershell, but I'm having an issue passing the arguments to it.

Example PS script -

```
$NumberOfTestRuns = 50
$RunCommand = "C:\MyApp\TestRunner.js --runs=$NumberOfTestRuns"
node $RunCommand
```

This returns the following error -

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\MyApp\TestRunner.js --runs=50'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:990:3
```

However, removing the arguments and just setting $RunCommand as -

```
$RunCommand = "C:\MyApp\TestRunner.js"
```

works correctly.

The script runs fine when I manually provide the arguments, it is only when trying to do so through powershell that I get any sort of issue.

What is the correct way to structure the command so that I can run the script from within my powershell script?

Comment: have you tried to do something like that `node $file $command`, and separate the file from the rest of the string,`$file = 'C:\MyApp\TestRunner.js ' $command = "--runs=$NumberOfTestRuns"`?? (note single and double quotes)

Comment: You may want to try formatting the full command as a string and then running it via `Invoke-Expression` something like 


`$command = "node C:\MyApp\TestRunner.js --runs=$NumberOfTestRuns"`

`Invoke-Expression $command`